# XML Serialization without csc.exe

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I am running into a problem with some .net controls that I created and which I want to use in Internet explorer while Protected Mode is enabled.
I get all kind of security prompts which relate to csc.exe trying to dynamically generate the serialized types.
Anyway my question is is there a .NET library out there that would allow me to serialize objects without triggering this csc.exe executable ?

Thank you

Comment: No, generating the serialization code is required.  Do it up front with sgen.exe.  Or Project + Properties, Build tab, Generate serialization assembly option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the sgen ([XML Serializer Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240.aspx)) tool. That will precompile the assemblies so that they don't need to be generated at runtime.

Comment: Thank you, one more question, where will .net look for the serialization assembly ? in the Gac ?

Comment: Just add a reference to this assembly in your project (it can be deployed to the same location as your .exe). It doesn't need to be GAC'd.